# Trying to print double quote form database into input field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a data stored in database valued xy". When I print this value in

tag, or  quote sign is visible. But when i output this value in input field, double quote isn't visible(it's still in database).

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $value ?>" />
```

The interesting thing is, when I use 2 single qoutes, output is equal to the value in database(xy''). Any ideas

Comment: use  htmlspecialchars on the output `echo htmlspecialchars($value)`

Comment: Think about the HTML it produces (`value="Kevin "The beast" Hansen"`). Use `str_replace('"', '&quot;', $value)` instead.

Comment: The first part is correct, but don't use the `str_replace`.  Use `htmlspecialchars()` to get everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($value) ?>" />
```